# Why stored procedure takes more time to execute compared to stored function for same code?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have created **stored-procedure** with `OUT` parameter to handle automate `INSERT` operations based on values of other tables. I also made **stored-function** for the same operation. I am facing a problem with execution time for both is heavily different which makes me worried and I don't know why is that.

Following table values in summary:

- 2016 rows in `emp_personal`

I am using `MariaDB 10.3.14`. I am testing with `HeidiSQL 10.1.0.5577`.
I also tried calling it from `Node.JS` using [MariaDB Node.js Connector](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/getting-started-with-the-nodejs-connector/). But in both cases, I had almost the same result.

**This is Stored Procedure**

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_auto_attendance`(
    OUT `result` INT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN 
DECLARE empId,done,isHoliday,isEmpHoliday,isWeekOff,isApprovedLeave,insertedRows INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE attendance VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'Present';
DECLARE empIds VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT '';

-- declare cursor with all employee Ids who are active
DECLARE empIds_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT id from emp_personal where isActive=1;

-- declare NOT FOUND handler
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

-- Check if today is holiday
SELECT COUNT(id) INTO isHoliday
FROM apexa_portal.public_holiday_dates
WHERE dateOfHoliday= CURDATE(); 

OPEN empIds_cursor;
    get_id: LOOP
        SET attendance = 'Present';
        FETCH empIds_cursor INTO empId;

            -- Following check if NOT FOUND handler has called, if yes exit loop else continue. NOTE: If you don't write this, it will be infinite loop.
            IF done = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE get_id;
            END IF;

            -- Check if public holiday for employee
            IF isHoliday > 0 THEN
                SELECT COUNT(phtd.isActive) INTO isEmpHoliday FROM public_holiday_template_days as phtd 
                LEFT JOIN emp_office_details as eod ON eod.publicHolidayTemplate=phtd.templateId 
                LEFT JOIN public_holiday_dates as phd ON phd.pub_holiday_id=phtd.holidayId
                WHERE eod.empID=empId AND phd.dateOfHoliday=CURDATE() AND phtd.isActive=1;
                IF isEmpHoliday > 0 THEN
                    SET attendance = 'Public Holiday';
                END IF;
            END IF;

            -- if not public holiday, Check if week off
            IF attendance <> 'Public Holiday' THEN
                SELECT COUNT(eowd.id) INTO isWeekOff FROM emp_office_working_days as eowd
                WHERE DAY=DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) AND eowd.empId=empId AND eowd.isActive=0; 
                IF isWeekOff > 0 THEN
                    SET attendance = 'Week Off';
                END IF;
            END IF;

            -- if not week off, Check if approved leave
            IF attendance <> 'Week Off' THEN
                SELECT COUNT(la.id) INTO isApprovedLeave FROM leave_application as la
                WHERE la.fromDate <= CURDATE() AND la.toDate >= CURDATE() AND la.empID=empId AND la.leaveStatus='Approved';
                IF isApprovedLeave > 0 THEN
                    SET attendance = 'Approved Leave';
                END IF;
            END IF;

            -- insert attendance
            INSERT INTO attendance_master(empID,dateOfAttendance,attendance) VALUES(empId,CURDATE(),attendance);
            SET insertedRows = insertedRows + 1;
    END LOOP get_id;
CLOSE empIds_cursor;
SET result = insertedRows;
END
```

**This is Stored Function**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `test_auto_att_func`()
RETURNS int(11)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN 
DECLARE empId,done,isHoliday,isEmpHoliday,isWeekOff,isApprovedLeave,insertedRows INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE attendance VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'Present';
DECLARE empIds VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT '';

-- declare cursor with all employee Ids who are active
DECLARE empIds_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT id from emp_personal where isActive=1;

-- declare NOT FOUND handler
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

-- Check if today is holiday
SELECT COUNT(id) INTO isHoliday
FROM apexa_portal.public_holiday_dates
WHERE dateOfHoliday= CURDATE(); 

OPEN empIds_cursor;
    get_id: LOOP
        SET attendance = 'Present';
        FETCH empIds_cursor INTO empId;

            -- Following check if NOT FOUND handler has called, if yes exit loop else continue. NOTE: If you don't write this, it will be infinite loop.
            IF done = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE get_id;
            END IF;

            -- Check if public holiday for employee
            IF isHoliday > 0 THEN
                SELECT COUNT(phtd.isActive) INTO isEmpHoliday FROM public_holiday_template_days as phtd 
                LEFT JOIN emp_office_details as eod ON eod.publicHolidayTemplate=phtd.templateId 
                LEFT JOIN public_holiday_dates as phd ON phd.pub_holiday_id=phtd.holidayId
                WHERE eod.empID=empId AND phd.dateOfHoliday=CURDATE() AND phtd.isActive=1;
                IF isEmpHoliday > 0 THEN
                    SET attendance = 'Public Holiday';
                END IF;
            END IF;

            -- if not public holiday, Check if week off
            IF attendance <> 'Public Holiday' THEN
                SELECT COUNT(eowd.id) INTO isWeekOff FROM emp_office_working_days as eowd
                WHERE DAY=DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) AND eowd.empId=empId AND eowd.isActive=0; 
                IF isWeekOff > 0 THEN
                    SET attendance = 'Week Off';
                END IF;
            END IF;

            -- if not week off, Check if approved leave
            IF attendance <> 'Week Off' THEN
                SELECT COUNT(la.id) INTO isApprovedLeave FROM leave_application as la
                WHERE la.fromDate <= CURDATE() AND la.toDate >= CURDATE() AND la.empID=empId AND la.leaveStatus='Approved';
                IF isApprovedLeave > 0 THEN
                    SET attendance = 'Approved Leave';
                END IF;
            END IF;

            -- insert attendance
            INSERT INTO attendance_master(empID,dateOfAttendance,attendance) VALUES(empId,CURDATE(),attendance);
            SET insertedRows = insertedRows + 1;
    END LOOP get_id;
CLOSE empIds_cursor;
RETURN insertedRows;

END
```

**Time to execute Stored Function**

```
SELECT `test_auto_att_func`();
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.328 sec. */
```

**Time to execute Stored Procedure**

```
CALL `sp_auto_attendance`(@res);
SELECT @res;
/* Affected rows: 6,049  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 2 queries: 00:01:21.6 */
```

[Stored Function Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91DzU.jpg) and [Stored Procedure Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7u50.jpg)

Can anyone please explain why this is happening? And if I am doing anything wrong, please let me know how should I correct it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference on performance on similar code when you run the code as a procedure vs as a function.

Most likely explanation (see Affected rows) is that at the the time of the function run, the cursor did not find any active persons whereas in the procedure run did, hence running the loop queries.

Comment: `INSERT` operation is successfully being inserted in function and procedure both. It works perfectly in both cases. I have a few `isActive=0` values as well so total rows are more than 2016. I have attached a screenshot for both outputs in question. Please check.

Comment: Do you use exactly the same dataset on both runs? Note that the code depends on the Holiday determination (btw, you have the attendance variable initialization error as you should set the initial value inside the loop).

Comment: Yes I used same dataset on both run. I have already initialized attendance variable.
`DECLARE attendance VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'Present';`

Comment: You have the `attendance` initialization outside the loop whereas it should be inside the loop (done separately for each row in `emp_personal`).

Comment: I did update value inside loop but execution time remain the same. I am worried about why execution time is this long.

Comment: You will do approximately 2016 * 3 queries (>6000) in total when you serialize the queries using a loop. Depending on indexes, some of those might not be optimized. You also repeat the same queries over and over again in case of a holiday. You could do all of is with just couple of queries (one for holiday and one for the insert). Do remember that you should think SQL targets as sets instead of separate rows.

Comment: I understood what you want to say. Can you update your answer with some example or make some changes in my code. It will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Why not give it a shot yourself. If you have problems, create another question with your attempted code, sample data and desired result.

Comment: I will definitely give it a shot. Thank you for your suggestion. :)